# Combine columns/fields from 50 large files into a single file

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I would like to know efficient way to combine all fields/columns from 
Multiple files into a single file. For every

File1:

```
1,fname1,one
2,fname2,two
```

File2:

```
1,lname1,lone
2,lname2,ltwo
```

Expected output

```
1,fname1, one,lname1,lone
2,fname2,two,lname2,ltwo
```

I have around 70 files like this with more than 100m records and 6 columns each.

Currently I'm trying to do this using hive join. It seem to be running forever -- almost 24 hours and still running. I need a better solution.

Comment: your question is not very clear...could you please specify the example properly

Comment: @Mahesh : Got any better way of doing this??

Answer (score 1):

Joining 70 files in a "naïve" way means that Hive has to execute 69 JOIN steps in order, with the left-side dataset getting bigger and bigger. 
If you break down the task explicitly with nested sub-queries -- i.e. joining A with B, C with D, then AB with CD, etc -- it will be less catastrophic, but still resource-intensive.

And in any case Hive will not take advantage of the fact that all files are already sorted *(see the documentation about Sort-Merge joins and the explicit requirement about bucketization)*.

Actually, your problem is as old as COBOL on mainframes. And I'm not sure it can be solved efficiently in a distributed way *(would require the files to be partitioned consistently to begin with)*. So please consider non-Hadoop solutions:

- If you want performance and an industrial-strength solution -- and
  have lots of cash to spend -- then buy a license of SyncSort or a
  similar tool
- If you just want to get the work done right now, download all files
  to a Linux box and try the good old `sort -m` command (not sure about
  the impact on RAM and Swap, though)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have already tried the approach of breaking into multiple joins. Infact my 24 hour timing is only after the breaking of joins into batches. The good old sort will not work here. This is a real big data problem and cannot be solved by good old sort.

Comment: @Amar: I have given an example too. I'm not sure what you are looking for when you say its not clear. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2: instead of multiple JOINs, what about creating a huge "sparse" table then running a massive GROUP BY?

- create a temp table with all expected 101 cols
- create 50 EXTERNAL tables mapped on your 50 source files (in 50 different directories) with 3 columns each, of course
- run 50 INSERT - SELECT queries to load every file into the temp table, in the appropriate columns i.e.

`insert into table SPARSE select ID, CODE1, VAL1, null, null, null, ... from SOURCE1 ;`
`insert into table SPARSE select ID, null, null, CODE2, VAL2, null, ... from SOURCE2 ;`

- run the final GROUP BY to flatten out the result: for a given ID there is only one non-Null value for CODE1, so Max(CODE1) will in effect mean *"get the value that came from SOURCE1 and ignore the Nulls from other sources"*

`select ID, Max(CODE1), Max(VAL1), Max(CODE2), ... from SPARSE group by ID`

I'm not 100% sure that it could beat your current 24 hours of processing; but it might be worth a try. Hopefully a single, massive, MapReduce job will be more efficient than multiple jobs for distributed JOINs.

~~~~

By the way, the massive GROUP BY will probably require careful tuning, i.e. checking that the number of Mappers & Reducers make sense (if not, try running statistics on the temp table and/or hard-setting some properties),  making sure intermediate results are compressed with Snappy or LZ4 (to reduce the I/O footprint with reasonable CPU overhead), etc. The usual stuff.

One major optimization might involve buckets on the temp table; but you cannot run multiple INSERTs against a bucketized table so you would have to try a massive INSERT OVERWRITE - SELECT UNION ALL SELECT UNION ALL... yuck.

Comment: Thanks seem reasonable. I had something else in mind. I don't know yet how to do but here is what I have in mind. Partition the data horizontally. I mean I will have all the columns built for all range of ids in a single file. next range will be in a different file